# Как найти индекс элемента в списке?

Tags: c

```
// элемент списка
typedef struct NODE {
 struct Node *next;
 struct Node *current;
 int data;
  } Node;
  //список
 typedef struct LIST {

int size;
Node *head;
 Node *tail;
 Node *current;
 Node *next;
 Node *key;
} list;

list * create_list(void)
{
    list *lt = malloc(sizeof(list));

    lt->size = 0;
    lt->head = NULL;
    lt->tail = lt->head;

    return lt;
}
void ListInsert(list *lt, int data)
{
    Node * node = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    node->data = data;
    node->next = lt->head;

    lt->head = node;
    lt->size += 1;
}
void * ListDelete(list *lt)
{
    if(lt->size == 0){
        /* Список пустий */
        return NULL;
    }

    Node *node = lt->head;
    void * ret_val = node->data;

    lt->size -= 1;
    lt->head = node->next;

    free(node);

    if(lt->size == 0){
      //  * Это был последний элемент */
       lt->head = NULL;
        lt->tail = NULL;
    }

    return ret_val;
}
/*int counter(list *lt, int val)
{
int i;
  struct Node* current = lt->head;
    while(current != NULL)
    {
        if( )
        {
             ;
            return(
        }
    }

}*/
void main ()
{
    list *st = create_list();
    ListInsert(st,1);
    ListInsert(st, 10);
    ListInsert(st, 3);
    ListInsert(st, 5);
    ListInsert(st, 4);
    ListInsert(st, 7);
    ListInsert(st, 6);
    ListInsert(st, 9);
    ListInsert(st, 8);
    ListInsert(st, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сама функция поиска индекса:

```
int indexInList(list *lt, int val)
{
  int ret = -1;
  int i = 0;
  Node* current = lt->head;

  while(current != NULL)
    {
        if( current->data == val)
        {
            ret =  i;
            break;
        }
        i++;
        current = current->next;
    }

   return ret;
}
```

И её тестирование в конце функции *main()*

```
val =8;
j = indexInList(st, val);
if (-1 != j)
  printf("Значение %d найдено по индексу %d\n", val, j);
else
  printf("Ничего не найдено!\n");
```